# How to fix "Cannot convert value of type '(CGFloat) -> Data?' to expected argument type 'Data'" error on this code?

Tags: swift

I tried to get image info for UIImage and then put them it through PFFile. 
But there is the below error on Xcode.

> "Cannot convert value of type '(CGFloat) -> Data?' to expected
>   argument type 'Data'"

```
let imageData = UIImage.jpegData(imageView.image!)

let file = PFFile(name: "320.jpg", data: imageData)
```

The error message is

> "Cannot convert value of type '(CGFloat) -> Data?' to expected
>   argument type 'Data'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
let image = UIImage(named: "320.jpg")
let file = PFFile(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0))
```

Comment: I changed to below code! So there is no error message on it. Thanks!! `let file = PFFile(data: image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!)`